# Compare only string part inside case class

Tags: scala, specs2

Is it possible to compare only part of string in property of case class.
Using scala specs2 lib.

Is there is a possibility to write such matcher?

```scala
CaseClass(property = Prop("very long string")) must beEqualTo(CaseClass(property = Prop("%long%")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [case class matchers](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.6.0/org.specs2.guide.matchers.CaseClassMatchers.html) like so

```
foo must matchA[Foo].property(_ must =~("long"))
```

Here is a working example

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import org.specs2._
import org.specs2.matcher.MatcherMacros

class QuickStartSpec extends Specification with MatcherMacros { def is = s2"""
 The 'Case class matchers' should
   match on a part of a string                                   $e1
                                                                 """
   def e1 = {
    case class Foo(property: String)
    val foo = Foo(property = "very long string")
    foo must matchA[Foo].property(_ must =~("long"))
  }
}
```

where

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "4.6.0" % "test",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-matcher-extra" % "4.6.0" % "test"
),
```

Comment: not sure if I missing some import, or what reason, but using this module i get compilation error: `Type Mismatch, expected: Matcher[this.foo], actual: Any`

Comment: @EdgarasBuchvalovas I've edited the answer with imports I used.

Answer (score 0):

With standard matchers

```
myCaseInst.property.myString must be matching(".*long.*")
```